# With jQuery, how can I select a single list item by data attribute and by that list's ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the correct jQuery syntax to select a list item by a data attribute in a specified list?  Here is a sample list:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li data-code="soup">Soup</li>
<li data-code="salad">Salad</li>
<li data-code="sandwich">Sandwich</li>
</ul>
```

From the above, I'd like to use both the ID for the list and the data-code that is applied to the list item in the selector.  Initially I thought something like this would work, but it's not.

```
var $menuItem = $('#menu li').attr('data-code', 'sandwich');
```

The interface I'm working on is more complex than this example, hence my reason for wanting to incorporate the ID in the selector. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you intend to use jQuery at all it is well worth reading through the [entire list of methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/) - I'm not suggesting you memorise them all or anything, but an hour or two spent browsing the list now will save lots of time later. (Or to handle your current requirement more quickly just look at the [list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [**Attribute Equals Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var $menuItem = $("#menu li[data-code='sandwich']");
```

We are referencing all `li` elements inside `#menu` whose attribute `data-code` equals `sandwich`.

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried this approach previously as well, but had a *space* between the li and the opening square bracket.  I appreciate the link to the Attribute Equals Selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('#menu li[data-code="sandwich"]');
```